# Regex : Match if exact prefix is present however ignore if the prefix has other attribute

Tags: regex

So i am trying to get a regex to work where i have a prefix `.i`. And i only want the action to run if someone types in the prefix without an attribute. So for example if someone types in `.i L`, it would be completely legal.

The regex i have tried using is `^[.i]` and `^[.i]?`
However with this if someone types something such as ".intro" the action still fires which i dont want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

playing with this [tester](https://www.regextester.com/100010) I found a this solution

`^(?:^|\W).i (?:$|\W)?`

which seems to work for the examples you gave.